# chargin partial web page with node express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, partial, ejs

I need help to charge my web page partialy, for example I want to listen music in a player while I am changing betwen different content. For my project is necesary to do this with node Expres and EJS but at the moment I can not find any module or solution for this. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a server side technology. As far as I understand what you want to achieve is single page web application. Try using client side Single page web application technologies like Angular or Backbone etc.